# Will I be able to remove 3M Electronics adhesive tape?

Tags: adhesive

I have an Energizer battery-powered LED lamp (model LW5072) that I wanted to add to a dark area. It sticks on with tape that has "3M Electronics" printed on the backing. Am I going to be able to remove this from painted wood later if I install it? If so, how?

Comment: 3M makes, at least, 100 different types of tape.  I could not find model LW5072. Can you post a link, please?  Also, what material will the tape be stuck to ?  Such as painted wood, drywall, tile.

Comment: The model is the LED lamp. I don't know what kind of tape it is other than it says "3M Electronics". Clarified: painted wood.